# Update query won't update my product list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having serious problems with my product details not updating. It fetches all the product information when I click edit but when I press the submit button to update the product details it does not have an affect on the database. I have been spending quite some time on this and have looked at solutions online as well. None of them seem to work

Here is my code :

```
                <?php

                  include("functions/mysqli_connect.php");

                  if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {

                    $get_id = $_GET['edit'];

                    $get_pro = "select * from shop where product_id='$get_id'";

                    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);



                   $row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro);
                    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
                 $pro_name = $row_pro['name'];
                 $pro_cat = $row_pro['category'];
                 $pro_description = $row_pro['description'];
                 $pro_quantity = $row_pro['quantity'];
                 $pro_price = $row_pro['price'];
                 $image = $row_pro['images'];

                }

                ?>
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">

                <head>

                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta name="description" content="">
                    <meta name="author" content="">

                    <title>SB Admin - Bootstrap Admin Template</title>

                    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
                    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

                    <!-- Custom CSS -->
                    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">


                    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
                    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

                    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->

                </head>

                <body>

                    <div id="wrapper">

                        <!-- Navigation -->
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['admin_username']; ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="functions/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Insert Products</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="view_products.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> View Products</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Edit Products</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> Delete Products</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </nav>

                        <div id="page-wrapper">

                            <div class="container-fluid">

                                <!-- Page Heading -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <form action="edit_pro.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="name">Product Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $pro_name;?>" >
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="category">Category</label>
                                                <select type="text" class="form-control" id="category" name="category" >
                                                <option><?php echo $pro_cat;?></option>
                                                <option>Henna</option>
                                                <option>Gliter</option>
                                                <option>Cajeput Oil</option>
                                                <option>Henna Cones</option>
                                                </select>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="image">Image</label>
                                                <input type="file" id="image" name="image"  ><img src="stock_images/<?php echo $image; ?>"width="60" height="60" />
                                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                                              </div>


                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="description">Description</label>
                                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"><?php echo $pro_description;?></textarea>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $pro_quantity;?>" >
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="price">Price</label>
                                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="<?php echo $pro_price;?>" >
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="form-group">
                                               <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $pro_id; ?>">

                                              </div>


                                              <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Stock"></a>.


                                        </form>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.row -->

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /#wrapper -->

                    <!-- jQuery -->
                    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

                    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
                    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



                </body>

                </html>



                <?php
                 if(isset($_POST['update'])){
                      //getting the text data from the form


                $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product_id']);
                $update_id = $pro_id;


                $pro_name = $_POST['name'];
                $pro_cat = $_POST['category'];
                $pro_description = $_POST['description'];
                $pro_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
                $pro_price = $_POST['price'];


                      $image = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
                      $image_tmp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

                      move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "stock_images/$image");


                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "Naina";
                $password = "Mhendi2015";
                $dbname = "farhanaina";

                try {
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                    // set the PDO error mode to exception
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                    $sql = "UPDATE shop SET name='$pro_name', category='$pro_cat', images='$image', description='$pro_description', quantity='$pro_quantity', price='$pro_price' WHERE product_id='$id'";

                    // Prepare statement
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                    // execute the query
                    $stmt->execute();

                    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
                    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
                    }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }

                $conn = null;
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using PDO and a prepared statement here. You can't feed a ready SQL query with the variable values into `PDO::prepare`. Quoting an example from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');

$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
```

The array you pass into your `PDO::execute` will replace each ? with a value in order of the values in the array. Otherwise, you can pass in an associative array and do it with named parameters:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
```